# Will MacOs reinstall delete all drivers?

Tags: macos, crash, kernel-panic

My Mac keeps crashing (kernel panic), and I've isolated the issue to Realtek driver (usb-c ethernet adapter). I want to know what is the easiest way to remove Realtek driver. I've tried an app called "Macpaw" and simlar, but they do not show up any apps called "Realtek".

Will a simple MacOS reinstall delete all this driver perhaps?

**** Panic Report ***
panic(cpu 2 caller 0xffffff801ccf3955): Failed mbuf validity check: mbuf 0xffffff8120a9ab00 len -12 type 1 flags 0x2 data 0xffffff8120a9abb6 rcvif en2 ifflags 0x8863*

Comment: Which Mac model and which macOS?

Answer (score 2):

No, just reinstalling the OS will not remove the drivers. You'd need to erase the volume and reinstall the OS, (and restore all your files, install apps, etc.)

The drivers on Realtek's website come with an uninstaller script.

https://www.realtek.com/en/component/zoo/category/network-interface-controllers-10-100-1000m-gigabit-ethernet-usb-3-0-software

(You shouldn't really need any drivers for a USB-Ethernet adaptor.)

For illustration, here's an image of the script's text. *(I've not included it as text, because you should satisfy yourself that the script is from Realtek.)*

[image]